# How do I concatenate multiple JPEG images into a PDF?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader, jpeg

I am trying to concatenate multiple JPEG images into a single PDF document. 
I used LibreOffice to make a great thumbnail collage, but it isn't acceptable to the agency to which I am trying to send it. They will only accept PDF, DOCX, RTF, JPG, or GIF files.

I've tried to download Adobe Acrobat because I heard it can help with what I'm trying to do, but there's no option on my laptop to open it. My son put Ubuntu on my laptop a couple months ago and I am not as familiar with it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use LibreOffice to save as a `PDF`, `DOCX`, or pretty much anything Word can do. To save as a PDF in Writer, simply click `File` and then `Export as PDF...` about halfway down. If you happened to use Impress or any other LibreOffice program, the steps are exactly the same.

To save as `DOCX` from Writer, go to `File` >> `Save As...` and change the `All Formats` box in the bottom right of the window that pops up to `Microsoft Word 2007-2013 XML (.docx)`. Simple as that ;).

If you need, I can edit my answer to include images.

Comment: Oh, my gosh, it really was just that simple. I think I'd been reading too much online for how to do it, that I got lost in the forest for the trees.

Answer (score 1):

A command-line way is to use the `convert` command from the `imagemagick` package:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
convert file1.jpg file2.jpg … filen.jpg  output.pdf
```

Comment: When I tried that, `convert` hogged so much memory it completely froze my computer…

Answer (score 1):

[`img2pdf`](https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/img2pdf) can do this:

> Losslessly convert raster images to PDF. The file size will not unnecessarily increase. It can for example be used to create a PDF document from a number of scans that are only available in JPEG format. Existing solutions would either re-encode the input JPEG files (leading to quality loss) or store them in the zip/flate format which results into the PDF becoming unnecessarily large in terms of its file size.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed to zacharee1 answer , but still if you can't find pdf option **just press alt and write pdf , you would be shown an option export to pdf**

if you don't know how to do something , just press the alt key , write that something and below would be the options , click on it.

**If you still can't get it  , update the question , there are many alternatives to do the above and if you think , your problem would be solved by microsoft word then do the below steps
**

steps to install microsoft office in ubuntu :

1. press ctrl + alt + t
2. type `sudo apt-get install wine`
3. enter the password, no letters would be shown , but enter the correct password
4. press enter
5. Download Microsoft Office from the website
6. after downloading the office , right click on setup.exe
7. open with -> other application
8. select wine, (if you can't find wine , then click on the view all application button and then scroll and find wine
9. press ok
10. install microsoft office next -> next -....->finish
11. insert your images in word
12. go to file , export and convert to pdf
13. although this procedure is long but you can run any windows program in ubuntu